How to use custom domain instead of localhost to connect to XAMPP on Windows Server through one of the network computers
I have an HP server on which VMware ESXi is installed. On it, I installed a Windows Server 2019 and then activated the Active Directory service. By creating a Zone in DNS Manager (like TEST.LOCAL) and completing the other necessary steps, I connected all the computers in the network to it.
I wanted to create a website in the local network that would be accessible from all the computers in the network. Therefore, I installed XAMPP on the Windows Server and ran WordPress on it.
Now, when I enter the IP of the Windows Server in the browsers of other computers, I can access the website. However, I want to access the website via the Zone Address I created in DNS Manager, for example, TEST.LOCAL.
Note: Accessing the WordPress site through the address http://TEST.LOCAL is only possible from the browser on the Windows Server. It cannot be accessed from the browsers on the other computers in the network.
What should be done to allow access to the site via the domain as well?
I followed various instructions but didn't get the desired result. For example,
1- I created a virtual host in the file located at: C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf as follows:
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.local
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName test.local

2- Ensuring that HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) ports are open. (windows defender firewall)
3- Test Network Connectivity:
Ping the ip server (192.168.18.2) from the client and the ping succeeds
Ping domain name (test.local) from the client and the ping succeeds.
